# Grouping and sorting in groups using linq

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, group-by

I have a table of data like this:

```
F1    F2    F3
---------------
20    942   50
60    942   330
20    941   205
20    943   250
60    941   120
```

I want to have My Data grouped into clusters with same F1. Whereas in each group, I want to have it sorted by F3 then F2 .

the result Data must be like this:

```
F1    F2    F3
---------------   
60    942   330
60    941   120
20    943   250
20    942   50
20    941   115
```

I will be appreciate you, if you can help me to deal with my problem.
Thanks alot

Comment: You sample data and your requirements differ. Please clarify what exactly do you need

Comment: Your output does not fit to your description. It looks more like GroupyBy F1, Sort By F2 descending, sort by F3 descending. There are many LINQ tutorials out there, you should elaborate on what you have tried and what your problem is. Also we need to know how the data looks in your code (I assume the table you posted is some text file?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could also be like:

```
var groups = dataset.GroupBy(item => item.F1);
foreach (var group in groups)
  foreach (var entry in group.OrderBy(g => g.F3).ThenBy(g => g.F2))
    .. do stuff ...
```

Or if you wan't to get one singe dataset back you could go with:

```
var groupedDataset =
  dataset
    .GroupBy(item => item.F1).
    .SelectMany(group => {
       var subSet = group.OrderBy(e => e.F3).ThenBy(e => e.F2);
       return subSet.Select(s => {
         F1 = group.Key,
         F2 = s.F2,
         F3 = s.F3
       });
    });
```

Although this looks rather complicated relative to the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a group by here, all you need is `OrderBy` :-

```
var result = data.OrderByDescending(x => x.F1).ThenByDescending(x => x.F2);
```

[Working Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lce4zQ)

Comment: It should be data.OrderByDescending(x => x.F3).ThenByDescending(x => x.F2);

Comment: @Artiom -And why is that? Check my fiddle, it's producing the exact answer what OP is expecting.

Comment: You are right. Question was misleading: want to have it sorted by F3 then F2 .

Comment: Your code won't work if data will be little different: check out https://dotnetfiddle.net/71kKg1

Comment: @Artiom - Different as in we can assume any data. Based on what OP has posted this will product the correct result.

Comment: He stated he needs grouping by first column, but sorted by 3rd column, than by 2nd. My sample works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by 3 columns would make it work:

```
data.OrderByDescending(x => x.F1).ThenByDescending(x => x.F3).ThenByDescending(x => x.F2);
```

for this input

```
F1    F2    F3
---------------
20    942   50
60    942   120
20    941   205
20    943   250
60    941   330
```

would give

```
F1    F2    F3
60    942    330
60    941    120
20    943    250
20    942    250
20    941    115
```

Comment: Going by your code `50 > 115` Is it? Better let OP clear what order he needs.

Comment: @RahulSingh where do you see `50`?

Comment: Check what OP is expecting as answer. He clearly wants the data to be sorted first by F2 then by F3. Which in my case is not needed. You have removed `50` from your output.

Comment: @RahulSingh yeah, something is wrong with that question. It's misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

First group by

var x = t.GroupBy(gp => gp.Name).OrderBy(group => group.Key).Select(group => Tuple.Create(group.Key, group.Count()));

Then sortby

x.OrderBy(gr => gr.Item2);